# Python Nose unit testing using separate (sequential) Python processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, nose, pyqt5

We use Python Nose for unit testing our GUI app components and application logic. Nose runs all tests in one process, not a big problem for the application logic but for a complex C++/Python lib like PyQt, this is a problem since there is "application wide" state that Qt creates, and it is hard to ensure that cleanup occurs at the right time such that every test method has a "clean Qt slate".

So I would prefer to have Nose start a separate Python process for each test method/function (or at least those that are flagged as needed this). I realize this would slow down the test suite but the benefit should outweigh the cost. I have seen the Insulate and the Multiprocess plugins but neither do this (Insulate only starts separate proc if a crash occurs -- Multiprocess just tries to use N process for N cores).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't starting & quitting the `QApplication` in the setup and teardown functions suffice?

Comment: That's what we do and I'm finding that it is not enough, perhaps because we are using some background threads and timers. @sebastian Sometimes the callbacks from the preceding test get called after test method has returned. I'd have to dig deeper to figure it out, it is not an issue when running the app itself which is why I was hoping for a process-per-test setting for nose rather than dig into the cause which only impacts unit tests  run in the same process not the app itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `nosetests --processes=1 --process-restartworker`

Comment: Thanks, it seemed promising. Nosetests completes about 50 test methods then freezes, not sure why. Runs all 500 tests when those parameters not given. Upvoted because on some test suites this approach might work but I can't tell if it really is the solution.